# Detect when controller fully loaded on route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem here with $broadcasting event to another controller. So here is the deal. In the footer of the website I have another controller loaded (the CMSController). Also I have a route '/help' where that controller is also loading and getting Help Center data from CMS.
There are links in the footer related to this. Let's say Terms and Conditions link. To get that data I need to go to '/help' route and call getHelpPage() function. That's the ongoing project structure which I'm working on.
So from footer I'm redirecting to '/help' route and broadcasting an event, which I'm listening on theCMSController and will call getHelpPage()

```
$scope.openHelpCenterPage = function openHelpCenterPage(slug) {
    if($location.path().indexOf('/help') === -1){
        $location.path('/help');
    }
        $rootScope.$broadcast('openHelpCenterPage', {slug: slug, from: 'footer'});
};
```

And in the CMSController

```
$rootScope.$on('openHelpCenterPage', function (event, obj) {
        $scope.getHelpPage(obj.slug);
});
```

The problem is that this is not working. I guess theCMSController is not loaded what this is happening. No errors in the console.

However.... Puring the boradcast into $timeout solves the problem, even with 0 seconds..

```
$timeout(function () {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('openHelpCenterPage', {slug: slug, from: 'footer'});
    },0);
```

But I don't feel like ti is a good solution. Any other ideas??? I've also tried to listen $routeChangeSuccess after listening  openHelpCenterPage, but again,no results....

```
$rootScope.$on('openHelpCenterPage', function (event, obj) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',function(){
    $scope.getHelpPage(obj.slug);
  })
});
```

maybe other ways to detect if controller is fully loaded????
Thanks a lot for your time. Hope I explained the problem well.

Comment: try to listen for events on a relevant scope with `$scope.$on(...)` instead of `$rootScope.$on(...)`; will anything change if you use `$emit` instead of `$broadcast` (for `$emit` you actually need `$rootScope.$on` though)?

Comment: thanks for reply. Unfortunately it's not working in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can Have your CMSController give one of rootScope's properties a nugdge, set a flag. And you can tell rootScope to check every 100ms for 1-2 seconds after you fire 1st event and then broadcast another only if flag is there.

But what I really reccomend you get mediator service. Just make a regular service but instead using it to communicate to back have a getter and setter to some private object. One controller sets object, other reads it when its ready. This way you know controller is ready since you are requesting the object in it.

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('mediatorService', function() {
      var _data= {};
        return {
            //setter
            save: function (data){
              _data= data;
            },
            //getter
            get: function(){
              return _data;
            }
        }
 })
```

Then in one controller you:

```
mediatorService.save(yourobject);
```

And in another:

```
$scope.data = mediatorService.get();
```

For me this is proffered way of communication of data between controllers. You basically have this options:

- **rootScope as mediator**
  **bad** - pollutes rootscope, can be missused elsewhere if not careful about names
  **good** - quick and with almost no code
- **events**
  **good** - can broadcast to all who listen, good when parent and children are involved
  **bad** - synchro issues like yours
- **route params**
  **good** - quick and easy when you got nested controllers
  **bad** - limited to use above
- **cookies and local storage**
  **good**  - if you need to persist on reload
  **bad** - workaround out of scope of angular - old browsers have only cookies. Defending on browser settings those might get deleted without you being able to react
- **mediator serivce**
  **good** - simple but effective with clear separation of role
  **bad** - requires a bit more boiler code

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. Unfortunately I tried and it's also not working. At the end of the controller I'm checking if mediatorService.get() is not an empty object and calling GetHelpPage function to get the page...But it's not working... Maybe there is another problem...

Comment: Have you injected service into both controllers and set the data in the first? Maybe you initialize 2nd controller before the 1st setups the data in mediator?

Comment: Yes,everything is properly done. 
In the first controller I'm setting the data into mediator service.
then checking in the second controller... check is passing. I'm console.log-ing the object,it's definitely there. Im passing the object into a function which is getting the help center page from CMS... no results.
However....Here is one interesting thing. I've tried to wrap it in the $scope.$$postDigest() callback and it worked.... So I'm starting to think thats controller loading is not the problem....Digest cycle is. I need to run that function in a proper way

Comment: That's.. odd.. You bound the service's getter in second controller to the scope? Digest should watch over it. When you set breakpoints into 1st controller, service and 2nd controller flow is going like this? 1st contoller fires a setter, service object is updated 2nd controller fires a getter and binds that object into a scope variable? If so IDK how can that go wrong.

Comment: I did it like this...in the first controller: the function that fires after clicking a footer link....
$scope.openHelpCenterPage = function openHelpCenterPage(slug) {
        if($location.path().indexOf('/account') === -1){
            $location.path('/account/help/main');
        }
        HCMediatorService.save(slug);

    };

in the secont controller:

$scope.HCServiceData = HCMediatorService.get();

if(!isEmpty($scope.HCServiceData)){

         $scope.getHelpPage($scope.HCServiceData);
    }

Comment: Oh, code is not formatted properly here. Sorry about that,
Anyway, if I get it correctly controller full load still doesn't mean that digest cycle is completed... wrapping it in $scope.$$postDigest() callback solves the problem....Also using $timeout works too, as it's fires after digest cycle finished... Still...is it safe to use one o this methods???

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding you have 2 controllers,and when you try to broadcast an event from one to second controller it is not listening  since it is not loaded fully..
to avoid this you can trigger an event from second controller after loading it and then proceed with normal flow
take a look at this sample .
**Ctrl2**

this will trigger an event when it is loaded

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    appName.controller('CMSController', Controller);
    Controller.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'CONSTANTS', '$location', 'PAGE_DATA'];

    function Controller($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        function inIt() {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('pageLoaded');
        }

        inIt();
    }

}())
```

**Ctrl1**

this will listen weather the another controller is loaded or not then trigger its broaddcast  like this

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    appName.controller('secCtrl', Controller);
    Controller.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'CONSTANTS', '$location', 'PAGE_DATA'];

    function Controller($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {

        var pageload = 0;
        $rootScope.$on('pageLoaded', function(event, obj) {
           $rootScope.$broadcast('openHelpCenterPage', {slug: slug, from: 'footer'});
        });
    }

}())
```

what i have explaind is a simple approach you can try from my understandings ..try changeing as per your requirements

Comment: thanks for answer. The problem is that the Ctrl 2 is loaded at that moment... For generating the footer links the CMSController is used. At the moment when I click the footer link 'pageLoaded' event will be already boradcasted on initial page load. The problem is that on click event user must be redirected to another route where the Ctrl2 (CMSController) loading again, but the GetHelpPages function already called before.